# How to create a scrollable screen in text mode with Python

Tags: python, text

I would like to create a scrollable screen in text mode, like the one obtained when typing help(object) in the interpreter. Is there a cross-platform module I can use to easily implement this?

For example:

```
>>> def jhelp(object):
>>>     text = # get text for object
>>>     display_text(text) # display a scrollable screen. How do I do this?
>>>
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> jhelp(l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pydoc import ttypager

def jhelp(object):
     text = # get text for object
     ttypager(text) # display a scrollable screen.
```

Comment: In linux, macOS or other *nix, `pydoc.pipepager("colored-string-here", pager="less -R")` is better because it handles colored output.

Comment: @This comment should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really want is `from pydoc import pager`. `ttypager` is a very reduced pager, but `pager` will automatically use a better pager (basically `less`) if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

look at `pydoc` module in the standard library