# Creating a "less"-like console pager interface for pysqlite3 database

Tags: python, linux, sqlite

I would like to add some interactive capability to a python CLI application I've writen that stores data in a SQLite3 database.  Currently, my app reads-in a certain type of file, parses and analyzes, puts the analysis data into the db, and spits the formatted records to stdout (which I generally pipe to a file).  There are on the order of a million records in this file.  Ideally, I would like to eliminate that text file situation altogether and just loop after that "parse and analyze" part, displaying a screen's worth of records, and allowing the user to page through them and enter some commands that will edit the records.  The backend part I know how to do.

Can anyone suggest a good starting point for creating that pager frontend either directly in the console (like the pager "less"), through ncurses, or some other system?

Comment: Why not pipe the output to `less`?  Why write your own version of `less`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213060/how-to-create-a-scrollable-screen-in-text-mode-with-python

Comment: I want to be able to edit records from the pager, so unless I can hook less's functions and use them as callbacks, it won't fit my needs.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: "Edit Records"?  So this is a complete character user interface with transactions? Not a pager?

Comment: Yeah, the whole shebang!  Less is a pager... and allows editing.  I really want to eliminate the memory hogging situation that I have right now with loading every database entry into a huge list in memory and printing it to an equally huge text file.  All I'll ever be able to look at is a single screen's worth of rows, so why not just select that number of records at a time from the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/). It is a console user interface library for Python. The [examples](http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html) should be more than enough to convince you that this is what you want, if you really want to go text-console UI.

I'd use something like [pygtk](http://pygtk.org) instead though.

Comment: Wow, that's very nice.  I like all the coloring options!  For simplicity I'll probably go with curses to start, but I'll definitely do something with urwid soon!  Gtk would be great, but I actually love urwid's retro look.  Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: urwid also uses curses, you just don't have to write most of the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

After looking around a bit, I found that less and other pagers actually use **curses**.  When I thought of curses I always imagined the blue-boxed interface with menus and mouse interaction.  These are library add-ons for curses, which offer *exactly* the basic terminal selection and editing control functionality I'm looking for.

[Tutorial on Python Curses Programming](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyCurses.pdf)

[Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html)

On the backend, when the user attempts to move the cursor above or below the currently displayed records, I'll have sqlite fetch me the next appropriate set of records for display.

Comment: Yes, I did have success with it.  Something notable about the experience, but unrelated to the curses part of it:  Initially, I thought the SQLite database queries wouldn't be able to keep up if the user continuously moved the cursor above or below the screen (as in holding down an arrow key).  This was true when I used an artificial primary key for indexing my entries.  Fetching was pretty slow.  The minute I switched to indexing based on the order of the items in the database (they were memory addresses so no duplicates were possible anyway), I could scroll real-time with no problem.

Comment: Looks like python.org moved their curses how-to, breaking my second link.  Here's the new location:  http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html