# How to open a text file in python and write only the first visible portion to the screen?

Tags: python, ubuntu, text-files

Here's the problem, I want to open a text file that has some ascii art at the top and then down below has a splurge about the program, the trouble is, by the time the file is open, its all ready scrolled down to the about text, so the ascii art is barely visible (unless I scroll back to the top). Is there any way to do this in such a way that it prints only only the first part and waits for a keypress to show more (kind of like viewing pages in the linux mandb), or something similar?

Here's my code so far, just to open and display the file:

```
    whereami = os.getcwd()
    importlogo = open(whereami+'/logo.txt', 'r')
    showlogo = importlogo.read()
    print showlogo
```

Comment: if you are going to vote my question down, could you at least tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I think it all boils down to the word "open"...

Comment: Are you saying that you want python to read the text file and then print some of it to the screen? Or that you want python to cause the text file to open in some text editor on the user's computer?

Comment: @commonNoob Fair enough.  Multiple things:  1) What are you asking?  How are you opening this file? *cat*? Reading it inside an actual python program and spitting it out?  Or what?  All I can get from it is 'python' 'file' 'open'.  No idea on the (important) specifics.  2)  What have you tried?  What exactly I would think you should try would depend on those specifics, but surely there's some idea in your head of what might work.  And if you did try something, mention that.  It makes people feel like you're asking a question and not just "gimme teh codez"'ing.

Comment: Ohh, I added the code, hope that helps.

Comment: I have removed my downvote.  What I suggest anyway, is either try to determine where the ASCII art is and don't print it out, print out the document parts at a time (pauses in between), or show part of it, wait for the user to press a key, show part of it, wait for a key press, so on.  None of the solutions are going to be particularly pretty.  You might just want to consider piping the output into *less*.

Comment: I'm writing a program that runs in the console. In my program, there is an about me page and i want to load part of my about me text file into the console window, but only the first part so the user can see the ascii art, and then can either scroll down, or touch a key to see more

Comment: @Corbin Thank you, that's exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how to pause the screen..

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213060/how-to-create-a-scrollable-screen-in-text-mode-with-python

Comment: @campos.ddc Didn't know that there's something already built to do that.  I was going to suggest a horrid, horrid approach :).

Comment: I tried the ttypager, and it does the same as print, starts at bottom.. the output from ttypager looks exactly like the output from my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on your problem:

```
import os
import sys


filename = 'logo.txt'
# Use join instead of hard-coding file separators
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
# You need to specify some kind of delimiter so you know
# where the logo ends. I couldn't think of a better way to
# only print part of the file.
delimiter = '------'


with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if delimiter in line:
            sys.stdout.write('Press any key to continue...')
            raw_input()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

It would help to know what the actual logo.txt file looks like.

Comment: okay, I tried this exactly, but for some reason its not picking up the delimiter? i put it in the file below the ascii art, and I even tried using symbols not included in the picture such as '$$$$$$' instead of '------'. Any clue whats going wrong?

Comment: wait i got it, WORKS! thanks a lot, my code is so jumbled, i had put it in the wrong screen, thanks a lot for this!! God bless!